# How can I make a variable a random variable in another variable?

Tags: java, random

The CL is to get a random Capital Letter & the rest is self explanatory.

```
String CL = CLetters.get(Randal.nextInt(CLetters.size()));
String L = Letters.get(Randal.nextInt(Letters.size()));
String N = Numbers.get(Randal.nextInt(Numbers.size()));
```

Then I want another variable `CLLN` to be set randomly to either `CL`, `L` or `N`.

I know that I could use an if statement, but then it wouldn't work with the rest of my script or class, I want to use a statement. Something like `String CLLN = (CL || L || N);`

Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: What is the statement `String CLLN = (CL || L || N);` supposed to do?

Comment: `String CLLN = (CL || L || N);` won't compile/

Comment: My goal is to get CLLN to be CL or L or N.

Comment: @user11102955 you can't achieve that, using that way. You have to pick a random, then use this random to decide which one to affect to CLLN

Comment: `I know that I could use an if statement, // but then it wouldn't work with the rest of my script or class` Why wouldn't it work with an if statement?

Comment: I'm wanting to make it where it will pull random letter and numbers till it gets a certain word, but i'm not sure how I would put that in an if statement.

Comment: If the desired value is a random choice of CL, L or N, put the three in an array and create a random number to index the array.

Comment: Ok, ill try that, Thanks.

Comment: Pick a random number from 1-3, for 1 use CL, for 2 - L, and for 3-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
String[] values = {
  CLetters.get(Randal.nextInt(CLetters.size())),
  Letters.get(Randal.nextInt(Letters.size())),
  Numbers.get(Randal.nextInt(Numbers.size()))
};

String CLLN = values[new Random().nextInt(values.length)];
```